# Keyboard.GetState().IskeyDown() not working as expected

Tags: c#, monogame

Here is the update method of my Player class:

```
timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
KeyboardState state = Keyboard.GetState();
if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up)) {
    if (currentFrame < 7) currentFrame = 7;
    if (timer >= delay) {
        if (currentFrame < 13) {
            currentFrame++;
        }
        else if (currentFrame == 13) {
            currentFrame = 7;
        }
        timer = 0;
    }
}
else {
    if (currentFrame > 7) currentFrame = 1;
    if (timer >= delay) {
        if (currentFrame < 6) {
            currentFrame++;
        }
        else if (currentFrame == 6) {
            currentFrame = 1;
        }
        timer = 0;
    }
}
sourceRect.X = currentFrame * 48 - 48; //I subtract 48 here to make the first frame 1 not 0.
```

And here is the draw method:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, sourceRect, Color.White);
```

What I am trying to do is that when the up key is down, the animation from frame 7 to 13 is shown (from a sprite sheet).
When the up key is not down, animation from frame 1 to 6 is drawn.
**Problem:** When I keep pressing the up key, it works fine, but when I press the up key just once, the animation gets stuck on the 7th frame.

Comment: The *timer* variable value is borken, it always has a large value.  Always larger than *delay*.

Comment: @HansPassant Why is that? I am setting the timer value to 0 if it's greater than delay

Comment: 0 is the time the user started the game, not when he pressed the key.

Comment: I thought it is the time since the last frame.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (currentFrame > 7) currentFrame = 1;
```

try change to

```
if (currentFrame >= 7) currentFrame = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the answer from @Silveor: First time through the loop, let's assume `currentFrame` is 1 and `timer` is less than `delay`.

1. You pressed up key, is `Keys.Up` is the key down.
2. `currentFrame` is less than 7 (it is 1) so set it to 7.
3. `timer` is less than `delay` so skip the code that increments `currentFrame`
4. Next time through that code: You only pressed the up key (didn't hold it down), so `Keys.Up` is not the key down.
5. `currentFrame` is not less than 7 (it is 7), so don't set it to 1
6. Let's assume `timer` is greater than `delay`. Still `currentFrame` won't be incremented or set to 1 because `currentFrame` is not less than 6 or equal to 6
7. There's no code to change `currentFrame` to anything else so it gets stuck on 7th frame.

So if you check for the value 7 in step (5) above then you can set it to 1. That's why @Silveor's answer is correct. :)

Comment: Can you explain 3? If timer is less then delay, why skip that part? it should execute instead.

Comment: Sure: Let's say you press and release the up key very quickly. The elapsed time (i.e., `timer`) will be a very small number. In the code path I outlined above, I'm assuming the value of `delay` is bigger than that small value of `timer`.

Comment: timer is not the time elapsed since up key was down. It is the time elapsed since the last frame.
P.S Can you please check this question? I am having a difficult time with it:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517999/cannot-load-music-file

Comment: Ok, I can say this without making any claims on what `timer` measures: You could experience the symptom in your question (stuck on 7th frame) in the scenario I outlined above. It will probably help you visualize it if you add `Debug.WriteLine()` calls to log the values of `timer`, `delay`, and `currentFrame` in various parts of that method.